# Calculate the volume bounded by the surface $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = x$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, surface-integrals

I need to solve:

Calculate the volume bounded by the surface

$$ (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = x $$

and not sure on how to do it.

If I move to spherical coordinates, I get that the equation gives:
$$
r^4=r\sin(\phi) \cos(\theta ) \Rightarrow r^3 = \sin(\phi) \cos(\theta )
$$
but I have no idea how to obtain the boundaries of integration from this...
Will you help me ?

I understand that probably: $0\leq r \leq \sqrt[3]{\sin(\phi) \cos(\theta )}$ , and that $0\leq \phi \leq \pi$, but what about $\theta$ ?

Thanks a lot in advance